# OAuth dialog doesn't work inside Facebook iframe

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, oauth

The page is question is https://apps.facebook.com/gentlemensbet/
The 'Begin Betting' button won't load the oauth screen for anyone.

However, if you open it in a new window, it seems to work just fine.
I can't find any reasonable explanation for this behavior and don't know how to correct this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `target="_blank"` or `target="_top"` to  your anchor tag.
You are trying to load a facebook URL in an iframe within a facebook page. That isn't permitted.

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

is the error logged in the console.
It is a preventive measure against [click-jacking](https://javascript.info/clickjacking).

Your link should be:

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?..." target="_blank"></a>
```