# my app is not available on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

http://apps.facebook.com/marksys
I could not see my app on the following url, but I am able to access on my web url.
http://peeplilive.in/demo

What's the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a facebook URL in an iframe within a facebook page. That isnt permitted.
It is a preventive measure against [click-jacking](http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking).
Error logged is

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by
>   X-Frame-Options.

**You should display a page, which has a button, asking the user to connect via facebook. Once he clicks the button, you can open an oauth dialog.** I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484321/oauth-dialog-doesnt-work-inside-facebook-iframe).

Comment: One day I tried the same for doing a kind of keylogger from another window to steal facebook passwords in js and got the same error: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options. Btw, nice answer +1 :-)

Comment: still i am not clear...i have made some changes....pls check and do need for me....https://apps.facebook.com/mark_system/. Still i get the same error....my app is available from my web url...peeplilive.in/demo.Please help me.

Comment: `https://peeplilive.in/demo/` is what you are requesting and that seems down when I access it directly as well. Also, `http://peeplilive.in/demo/` displays a blank page.

Comment: I am sorry...pls check it now sir....

Comment: when you access the `https://` version of your site. The connection is refused. The same error is seen on the facebook page. Use the `http://peeplilive.in/demo` page, and not the `https://` as you have currently used, in your facebook application.

Comment: sir,the browser redirects automatically to https://...even though i give the url as.http://apps.facebook.com/mark_system. Where to change the settings

Comment: It is working now. `http://apps.facebook.com/mark_system/`. I guess you've changed the URL. Please accept the answer, if it solved your issue.

Comment: sir...it works on ie9....but why not on chrome and mozilla

Comment: I am using chrome. It is working fine. Maybe you are loading an older version. Clear cache and retry.

Comment: How to get the user id from google login and store it in my website for future login to my website?Pls do me a needful help.

Comment: Ask a different question here on Stackoverflow. Maybe someone can help